# I need to split text delimited by paragraph tag

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
$text = "<p>this is the first paragraph</p><p>this is the first paragraph</p>";
```

I need to split the above into an array delimited by the paragraph tags. That is, I need to split the above into an array with two elements:

```
array ([0] = "this is the first paragraph", [1] = "this is the first paragraph")
```

Comment: `explode('</p><p>', $text);`?

Comment: @devdRew What about the first and last? There would be no closing tag before the first and no opening tag after the last. (appreciate it's 7 years old now)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove the closing `</p>` tags as we don't need them and then explode the string into an array on opening `</p>` tags.

```
$text = "<p>this is the first paragraph</p><p>this is the first paragraph</p>";
$text = str_replace('</p>', '', $text);
$array = explode('<p>', $text);
```

To see the code run please see the following [codepad entry](http://codepad.org/tkECpVvl). As you can see this code will leave you with an empty array entry at index 0. If this is a problem then it can easily be removed by calling `array_shift($array)` before using the array.

Comment: This is the best answer, since it accounts for </p> being optional.

Comment: explode("<p>", str_replace("</p>", "", $text));

Comment: @BeRecursive Yes, the code can be shortened to one line, but it is easier to read and understand broken across multiple lines. I try to make my answer as clear as possible so all levels of PHP user can understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree your answer is well explained

Comment: @Treffynnon: +1 You're readable code split over multiple lines is appreciated by this PHP newbie.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else who finds this, don't forget that a P tag may have styles, id's or any other possible attributes so you should probably look at something like this:

```
$ps = preg_split('#<p([^>])*>#',$input);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I was not able to find any reasonable solution in an hour of looking for stactverflow answers. If you have string full of html tags (p tags) and if you want to get paragraphs (or first paragraph) use `DOMDocument`.

`$long_description` is a string that has `<p>` tags in it.

```
$long_descriptionDOM = new DOMDocument();
// This is how you use it with UTF-8
$long_descriptionDOM->loadHTML((mb_convert_encoding($long_description, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')));
$paragraphs = $long_descriptionDOM->getElementsByTagName('p');
$first_paragraph = $paragraphs->item(0)->textContent();
```

I guess that this is the right solution. No need for regex.

edit: **YOU SHOULD NOT USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML.**

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "<p>this is the first paragraph</p><p>this is the first paragraph</p>";

$exptext = explode("<p>", $text);

echo $exptext[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $exptext[1];
```

//////////////// OUTPUT /////////////////

this is the first paragraph
this is the first paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$textArray = explode("<p>" $text);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($textArray); $i++) {
    $textArray[$i] = strip_tags($textArray[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is somewhat consistent you can use a simple split method as:

```
 $paragraphs = preg_split('~(</?p>\s*)+~', $text, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Where the [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) will look for combinations of `<p>` and `</p>` plus possible whitespace and separate the string there.

As unnecessary alternative you can also use [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath) or [phpquery](/questions/tagged/phpquery) to *extract* only complete paragraph contents using:

```
 foreach (htmlqp($text)->find("p") as $p) { print $p->text(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$text = "<p>this is the first paragraph</p><p>this is the first paragraph</p>";

$array;

preg_replace_callback("`<p>(.+)</p>`isU", function ($matches) {
    global $array;
    $array[] = $matches[1];
}, $text);

var_dump($array);

?>
```

This can be modified, putting the array in a class that manage it with an add value method, and a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$text = "<p>this is the first paragraph</p><p>this is the first paragraph</p>";
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string('<data>'.$text.'</data>')),1);
print_r($array['p']);
?>
```